# Where to get sample input and output of large Hamiltonian graphs?

Tags: algorithm, input, graph, output

I am trying to find a repository hosting input and output files of large Hamiltonian graphs to test how well my estimation algorithm works. Does anyone know such a place to get sample graphs with their Hamiltonian cycles to test against?

Comment: Please take a look @ codeforces and topcoder. Maybe you find some useful inputs there.

Comment: The close votes are ridiculous. In this case, there are well accepted sets of test instances, used by academia/industry. The general reasoning against such questions do not make sense in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [TSPLIB](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/), which is a collection of sample instances for the Traveling Salesman Problem (and related problems) from various sources and of various types. It also has a section for Hamiltonian Cycle problems, with thousands of inputs and output files.

For example, the [FHCP Challenge Set](http://www.flinders.edu.au/science_engineering/csem/research/programs/flinders-hamiltonian-cycle-project/fhcpcs.cfm) is a collection of 1001 instances of the Hamiltonian Cycle Problem, ranging in size from 66 vertices up to 9528 vertices, with an average size of just over 3000 vertices.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! So helpful!